# Tensorflow queue is not filled

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm very sorry but I still have some problems dealing with tensorflow and hope to get some help here....

I did the first solution suggested by Sraw at [Tensorflow does not terminate using batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807493/tensorflow-does-not-terminate-using-batches) but I get the following error now

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 30, current size 0)
 [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

I already tried to use

```
try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        # Run training steps or whatever
        sess.run(train_op)

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
```

but it does not work as well.
The file dataset.csv is existing. But I can't figure out if there is a way to check if it is read correctly by my script.

The hole file looks like

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from urllib.request import urlopen

num_attributes = 15
num_types = 7


def read_from_cvs(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [[] for col in range((num_attributes+2))]  # no defaults
    attributes = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    features = tf.stack(attributes[1:-1])  
    #labels = tf.stack(attributes[-1])  
    labels = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(tf.stack(attributes[-1]), tf.uint8), num_types)
    return features, labels

def input_pipeline(filename='dataset.csv', batch_size=30, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    features, labels = read_from_cvs(filename_queue)

    min_after_dequeue = batch_size
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    feature_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [features, labels], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return feature_batch, label_batch


def tensorflow():
    x, y_ = input_pipeline()

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_attributes, num_types]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_types]), name="bias")

    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for _ in range(1200):
        sess.run(train_step)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

    #correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    #accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    #print(sess.run(accuracy, ))

    sess.close()

def main():
    tensorflow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope someout could provide some help.

**Edit:**
I figured out that the problem was my csv file which contained a format failure.

Comment: `input_pipeline(filename='dataset.csv...` here filename expects absolute path

Comment: os.path.abspath('zoo.data') should provide absolute path and also providing the absolute path directly does not work